# ¿Cómo capturar un error en una petición HTTP en Angular2 antes que se subscriba?

Tags: angularjs-2.0, http

Actualmente tengo servicios que mapean (preprocesan) peticiones http devueltas por un Servidor, un ejemplo de un servicio seria el siguiente:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyServicioSerivce {
    private baseUrl: string;

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.baseUrl = 'http://my-api-rest.dot.com'; // url ficticia para el ejemplo
    }


    public traerArticulos() {
        const headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.UserToken
        });
        const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this.http.get(this.baseUrl, options).map(response => response.json());
    }
}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es capturar y procesar el error de la petición en caso de que por ejemplo el token no sea valido u ocurriese un error de autenticación en el servidor u ocurriese un problema al procesar la petición. De lado de un `Controller` al subscribirse se lo puede manejar así:

```
service$ = this.myServicioService.traerArticulos().subscribe(articulos => {
    console.log(articulos);
}, error => {
    console.error('Ocurrió un error')
});
```

Ocurre que necesito algo mas genérico, pero al intentar hacer lo mismo en la función `map()` me da error, osea no puedo hacer lo siguiente dentro del servicio:

```
return this.http.get(this.baseUrl, options).map(response => {
        return response.json();
    }, error => {
        // hacer algo para manejar el error de lado de servidor
        return error;
    });
```

Comment: Si actualiza la dependecia `Http` por `HttpClient` es posible desarrollar interceptores con lo que es posible realizar un filtrado tanto del *request* como del *response* de los servicios conectados al API. [Interceptores Angular](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8)

Comment: `return this.http.get(this.baseUrl, options).first().toPromise().then(function(value) {
   // cumplimiento
  }, function(reason) {
  // rechazo
});` Algo así tal vez te pueda ayudar, aunque seria mejor pasar a HttpCliente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estuve revisando las recomendaciónes sobre [Interceptores en Angular2](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8) 
me parecio una propuesta interesante pero no entendi como implementarla completamente, actualmente lo hago via un servicio Encapsulador de `Http` que hace lo siguiente

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpClientService {

    constructor (
        private dataSessionService: DataSessionService,
        private router: Router,
        private http: Http
    ) {}

    get(url: string) {
        const headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.dataSessionService.authToken
        });
        const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this.http.get(url, options);
    }


    post(url: string, body: any) {
        const headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.dataSessionService.authToken
        });
        const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this.http.post(url, body, options);
    }
}
```

Volviendo al problema, una solución simple sin interceptores ni uso de `.do()` para capturar los errores cuando usas `map()` es usar `.catch()` de la siguiente forma,

```
service.function()
    .map(response => response.json())
    .catch(error => {
        //Hacer algo 
    })
```

De ahi se podria sobreescribir por ejemplo `get` de `HttpClientService` para manejar las peticiones de la siguiente manera:

```
get(url: string) {
    const headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.dataSessionService.authToken
    });
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.get(url, options).map(response => {
        return response;
    }).catch(err => {
        const _err = err.json();
        if (_err.Code === 401) { // Unauthorized
            // borrar token;
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        }
        return Observable.throw(err.json());
    });
}
```

`return Observable.throw(err.json());` Permitira que el error se siga propagando hasta un manejador correspondiente, en resumen funciona, pero dejo abierta la pregunta
a una mejor solución como usar Interceptores que tengo de tarea pendiente.